# maven android plugin:No Android SDK path could be found

Tags: java, android, maven, m2eclipse

I use the `maven-android-plugin` version 3.3.2. When I try to build my android project I have the following exception:

> `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException`: No Android SDK path could be found. You may configure it in the plugin configuration section in the pom file using `<sdk><path>...</path></sdk>` or `<properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties>` or on command-line using `-Dandroid.sdk.path=...` or by setting environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`

However environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` is set to android sdk path.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Windows or Linux? What happens if you type `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` in command line? Does that point to a valid SDK path?

Comment: I work on linux. when i do echo ANDROID_HOME, i get the path of sdk installation

Comment: What happens if you run `adb`, `aapt` commands? Can the OS resolve them?

Comment: running adb give me Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31 ....but aapt is unknown command.

Comment: Then you need to add to your system PATH the path to build tools as well. Maven fails because it cannot resolve `aapt`, `aidl` and whatever other tools it uses.

Comment: @gunar : no, there's no need for that. The Android plugin will be able to determine where those tools are, as long as ANDROID_HOME is set.

Comment: thank you @gunar for your efforts

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like, while the env var is available on the shell you run, it isn't available on the shell Maven runs.

Regardless, instead of working around it, it's best to create [a settings file](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) with the property set. A minimal one would look like this (writing off the top of my head, as I don't have my settings file available now) :

```xml
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>android-settings</id>
        <properties>
            <android.sdk.path>/path/to/android/sdk</android.sdk.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>android-settings</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Throw it into your `.m2` folder or set it via Eclipse in `Window`->`Preferences...`->`Maven`->`User Settings`.

Answer (score 6):

**From the documentation**

You may configure it in the `android-maven-plugin` configuration section in the `pom.xml` file using `<sdk><path>...</path></sdk>` or `<properties><android.sdk.path>...</android.sdk.path></properties>` or on command-line using `-Dandroid.sdk.path=...` or by setting environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`.

**Solution 1**

I have defined an Android SDK system variable called `ANDROID_SDK` (instead of `ANDROID_HOME`) and referenced it in my `pom.xml` this way:

```
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>...</name>
  <description>...</description>

  <properties>
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_SDK}</android.sdk.path>
    ...
  </properties>
```

**Solution 2**

As an alternative you can also configure it in the `android-maven-plugin` section:

```
<plugin>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${android-maven-plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
  <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
  <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
  <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
  <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
  <sdk>
    <android.sdk.path>${env.ANDROID_SDK}</android.sdk.path>
    <platform>16</platform>
  </sdk>
  <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Solution 3**

As a third option you can set the SDK from the command line passing an argument to Maven:

`mvn clean install -Dandroid.sdk.path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes i solved this issue.By adding settings.xml file in ~/.m2 folder

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <android.sdk.path>
                  ANDROID SDK PATH
                </android.sdk.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles> <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>android</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles> 
</settings>
```

and open your android-bootstrap-master app and open pom.xml file and check the following line

```
<sdk>
    <platform>16</platform>
</sdk>
```

16 is the currently installed or not sdk level

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set
`export ANDROID_HOME=pathToAndroidSdk` 
right from the target deploy repository.

Variable will be set only for current shell and all processes started from current shell.