# MAVEN Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 16 not available

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I have a working android app on my Android Studio (windows) and I am trying to create an apklib with MAVEN for the project.

When I run compile on MAVEN (3.0.5) I get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project userprofile: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources failed: Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 16 not available. This command should give you all you need:
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\android update sdk --no-ui --obsolete --force
```

I run the above command for update sdk but no luck (it was successful, but I keep get the above error). My SDK Manager shows that API 16 is installed.

Any ideas? (all questions on web conclude to install the API on SDK Manager :( )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error building Android project with Maven: Platform/API level 16 not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023461/error-building-android-project-with-maven-platform-api-level-16-not-available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---EDIT---

There was also an error because I had my settings.xml set to the incorrect android SDK home path.  I updated my ~/.m2/settings.xml file to the correct SDK path and set my $ANDROID_HOME variable to the correct path and this was fixed.

---

I was able to get past this error with the following changes:

1. [Update to maven 3.1.1](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. in my pom.xml I changed

`<plugin>
          <groupId> com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 </groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>`

To: 
  `<plugin>
          <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
      </plugin>`

(note this change both updates to the [latests plugin version (3.8.1)](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2%7Candroid-maven-plugin%7C3.8.1%7Cmaven-plugin) and specifies the platform for the sdk)

1. I ran `$PATH_TO_YOUR_ANDROID_SDK/android update sdk --no-ui --all --force`
2. I deleted my ~/.m2 directory
3. I ran `mvn clean install` and everything worked

Comment: this only happens to me while building the project through jenkins. In my scenario something happens related to jenkins, If I try to build via mvn console (using "mvn compile" for instance) everything goes perfectly, do you have any advice?

Comment: What exactly does 1. do? I did it and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @taylorstine Why/how would you have the SDK path set in your maven settings.xml? o_O. I modified my pom as you describe, but during the build Maven keeps donwloading 3.6.0 android-maven-plugin. It just ignores the 3.8.1. In my case the plugin is trippin' about API level 15, although it is installed. Weird.

Comment: Got it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133913/maven-android-pluginno-android-sdk-path-could-be-found

Comment: And that solved it. So the shell what the plugin starts doesn't pick up the ANDROID_HOME env variable. Crafting a settings.xml helped. Unbelievable.

Comment: What do we do now that the android command is not available. When running `$PATH_TO_YOUR_ANDROID_SDK/android update sdk --no-ui --all --force` : I get the error: `The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`